# Copying with criteria, get freeze out with big data

Tags: excel, vba

I have lots of columns (eg. 110) with 3000 rows with ID and an order ID to copy the data.
The code is running with 6 column amd 20 rows, but not with bigger sheet.

Tried different copy method, but only cells to cells are working.
Range.Copy doesn't, gets run-time error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.

```
Sub Gomb1()
    Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long, lastmh As Long, lastdatacolumn As Long, idmh As Integer, iddata As Integer, y As Integer, x As Integer, i As Integer

    lastrow = Worksheets("data").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    lastmh = Worksheets("MH").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastdatacolumn = Worksheets("data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For y = 2 To lastmh
        idmh = Worksheets("MH").Cells(y, 2).Value

        For x = 3 To lastdatacolumn    
            iddata = Worksheets("data").Cells(4, x).Value

            If idmh = iddata Then
                For i = 4 To lastrow
                    Worksheets("data").Cells(i, x).Copy
                    erow = Worksheets("report").Cells(Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp).Row
                    Worksheets("data").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("report").Cells(erow + 1, y)
                Next i 
            End If
        Next x
    Next y

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: At what line are you getting the error?

Comment: It freeze out, rather than error, but sometimes I'm able to break the cycle, and get this line error
      ' Worksheets("data").Cells(i, x).Copy'
after that I can see in the report sheet 2 columns copied, but thats it.

Comment: Now work with .Range .Copy.
The data is too big for this method, I think.